# Methods of adding columns of check boxes to QTreeView to the left of the tree?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I'm trying to add a couple of columns of check boxes to the left of the tree part of a QTreeView.  As far as I can tell, using just the QTreeView all of the columns must be to the right of the tree controls.

I would probably consider using two widgets but synchronization and the trick that the check box for non-leaf nodes needs to reflect the mixed state of the children (the details of which are outside of the scope of this question) seem to aggravate the problem - it seems that the state of the two widgets would need to be tightly coupled in order for the left widget (possibly a list of check boxes) to display the correct check boxes based on the visible nodes in the right widget (the tree).

What are some of the better ways to accomplish this?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image: tree view]

Comment: Better way - custom delegates + `QStandardItemModel` with custom roles.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like QTreeView::setTreePosition() does the trick.